# Why using determinant equal to zero

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am stuck at a step in some calculations from my teacher:

we have that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are non-zero and that $u_1>0$.

$   \begin{bmatrix}
        u_1 & 4  \\ 
        4 & u_1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ *  $\begin{bmatrix}
        x_1   \\ 
        x_2   \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ = 
$0$
$$-$$It seems like a trival step but the teacher uses :

$det\begin{bmatrix}
        u_1 & 4  \\ 
        4 & u_1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ = $0$
$$-$$
How comes that we use the determinant to solve for our $u_1$?

Comment: Are those matrices or determinants

Comment: The two top are two matrix multiplications and the one under is the determinant of the 2x2 matrix.

Comment: A good example for why determinants are useful despite the fact that Gauss' algorithm already provides a way to tell when a system has a non-unique solution. Imagine trying to solve for $u_1$ and $u_2$ from the first equation, not knowing what the $x_i$ might be!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if a square homogenous linear system has a non-zero solution, then the matrix cannot be invertible and so has determinant equal to zero.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a justification. I change notation a bit. Suppose that we have a pair of equations $$ ax + by = 0\\cx+dy =0,\\$$ where $x$ and $y$ are not both zero.
If $x =0$, then we have $by = 0$ and $dy =0$, so that $b = d = 0$ since $y \neq 0$, and the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{clcr} a& b\\c&d \end{array}\right)$ has zero determinant. So suppose that $x \neq 0$.

Multiply first equation by $d$ and second equation by $b$ to get:
$$ adx + bdy = 0\\bcx+bdy =0.\\$$ Now subtract the second equation from the first to get $(ad-bc)x + 0y = 0$. Since $x \neq 0$, we must have $ad-bc = 0$ and the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{clcr} a& b\\c&d \end{array}\right)$ still has zero determinant.

On the other hand, if $ad-bc = 0$, we can solve the system of equations by taking $ x = d, y =-c$ and also by  taking $x = -b, y = a$, so we have found at least one non-zero solution to the system of equations, unless $a = b = c = d = 0$. But if $a = b = c = d = 0$, then any choice of $x$ and $y$ not both zero gives a non-zero solution.